# Add push notifications when new articles appear on our database using ionic cloud or firebase?

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, push-notification

I have server built on wordpress php and I have website.

My website delivers articles to subscribed users. Users can subscribe to different articles.

Now we have developed ionic app that uses website api to retrieve articles but in mobile app.

Is there a chance to add push notifications for users when new articles appear on our database using ionic cloud or firebase? Is there some tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

Yes really you can do that there is a [complete guide in ionic document about Push notification](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/) . After you integrated push notification according to their document.
They will provide a token for each device register with push notification. You can store them in your database and you can use those token to send push notification when you add a new articles. They will provide relevant [API end point](https://docs.ionic.io/api/endpoints/push.html#get-notifications-notification_id-messages)  for do that. You can configure your API end point according to  [this configurations](https://docs.ionic.io/api/http.html).